# SQLXML error when trying to call getSQLXML on ResultSet

Tags: java, xml, jdbc, db2, resultset

I am trying to obtain XML data from database. The column is of type XML and I'm using SQLXML. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLXML.html) But I'm getting the following error when trying to call method getSQLXML on ResultSet.

**Code Snippet:**

```
ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
   System.out.println("ResultSet has something");
   xml = rs.getSQLXML("xml_col"); //Exception occuring here
}
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.j.getSQLXML(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/sql/SQLXML;
```

Also I am using JDBC driver version 3.5 and database version is DB2 9.7.

Can someone please advise me on what I may be doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: This error indicates that your driver is a JDBC 3 driver. the [`getSQLXML`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getSQLXML-int-) method was added in Java 6/JDBC 4. You might want to check with IBM if a JDBC 4 (or higher) driver is available for your database,